# Can only enter as guest ,lost password

Tags: data-recovery, password-recovery

I can only open my asus laptop as a guest so can reset my lost password can anyone help

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the solution that was pointed out in the comment, I have another way to do the same thing. It is a modification to one of the solution in the [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

1. Power on your computer
2. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the GRUB prompt.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit.
4. Move your cursor by pressing <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to `kernel...` or `linux...`, then press <kbd>End</kbd>
5. Put a space at the end of the line and add the word `single`
6. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> and it will boot to the single user mode
7. You will be logged into root now, without asking for a password.
8. Use the command `passwd <username>` and provide the password of your choice.
9. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to reboot

This will take you to normal OS boot and you can login to your user with the chosen password.